# Quicksight calculated field trying to parseJson from MYSQL

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am trying to extract fields in data in a MYSQL 5.7 database. I have a field that contains JSON data and I am trying to use the QuickSight Data Prep tool to create a calculated field to extract data from this column. I use parseJson({results}, "$[0].rsid") but that doesnt work.

The JSON data is in this format
results.column = [{rsid:"bla", value:"blabla"},  ...etc]
ie. it is in an array of dictionaries

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your example is not actual JSON (missing quotes around object keys). Is your actual data proper JSON? I assume so and you're just posting a quick example but `parseJson` won't work otherwise so just to be sure...

Comment: Also note that there are some pretty specific requirements document on exactly _where_ `parseJson` is supported. If you haven't read it be sure to note the SPICE requirements and the column type requirements: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parseJson-function.html

Answer (score 1):

Try `parseJson({results}, "$.0.rsid")`

Comment: Is it possible to parse an array? If so, can you provide a simple example, please?